# Drive a capacitance load with a very large output resistance analog voltage source

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, driver, circuit-design

I have a signal source with a very high output resistance. The output of this source is connected to the input of comparator. Actually the input capacitance of comparator is not large (about 20fF). However, the output resistance of the source is very large (10Mohm). So, is there a way to drive a capacitance load with large output resistance source here?
The voltage source is analog signal not digital one.

Comment: Please describe in more detail "is there a way to drive it."  Yes, it will currently drive as you described it, but it will be very susceptible to noise, have slow response times, etc.  Without knowing what your goal or spec is, it will be hard to help you.  You can always use an opamp buffer between them to drive it with low impedance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiVybe296bMAhUlKcAKHW5dBOYQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Frfdesign.com%2Fmag%2F511RFDF3.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFr94LRXUUZUAYrlRDMYuWEM2s1cw&sig2=iGk14yJTt8zzqahgoFNTaw&cad=rja) link entitled "All terminators are not created equal" it discusses the end-to-end capacitance of various resistor packages. Typically an 0603 looks like this when modeled: -

[image]

Now I don't know what form your 10 Mohm resistor takes but if it is the commonly used 0603 package then the 0.25 pF self capacitance will ensure that at high frequencies the signal is still largely the same because it is only driving 0.02 pF i.e. the 0.25 pF dominates.

Having said all that I've never come across a comparator that has input capacitance this low and any PCB tracking will likely have ~0.1 pF to ground at the very least so you need to understand the bigger picture.

Answer (score 1):

I think more information could be added to your question to help get a direct answer, but here are a few thoughts.

Any analog signal could be driven really. There is simply different attenuation of the signal for different frequency components. If the analog signal is limited to be only composed of frequencies whose periods are much longer than the time constant of the circuit (output resistance * input capacitance) then no attenuation will occur and your signal will pass through easily. You could even work at higher frequencies if the analog signal is bandlimited since the attenuation would be approximately the same for all frequencies if the bandwidth is small. Then the comparator could easily do something such as flag overvoltages or undervoltages.

Hope this helps some.